# Rails Everyday Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need the system to run the following code everyday but I don't know how to do accomplish this.

```
@user = User.all
date = Date.today
if date.workingday?
  @user.each do |user|
    if !Bank.where(:user_id => user.id , :created_at => (date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day) , :bank_type => 2 ).exists?
        banco = Bank.new()
        banco.user = user
        banco.bank_type = 2
        banco.hours = 8
        banco.save
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at the [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most conventional way is to set this up to be executed with [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) in a [`cron` job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

There are tools like [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) that make it easier to create these jobs by defining how often they need to be executed in Ruby rather than in the peculiar and sometimes difficult to understand `crontab` format.

As a note, `User.all` is a very dangerous thing to do. As the number of users in your system grows, loading them all into memory will eventually blow up your server. You should load them in groups of 100 or so to avoid overloading the memory.

Additionally, that `where` clause shouldn't be necessary if you've set up proper `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships here. I would expect this could work:

```
unless (user.bank)
  user.create_bank(
    bank_type: 2,
    hours: 8
  )
end
```

It's not clear how `created_at` factors in here. Are these assigned daily? If so, that should be something like `bank_date` as a `DATE` type column, not date and time. Using the `created_at` timestamp as part of the relationship is asking for trouble, that should reflect when the record was created, nothing more.

Comment: thanks for the advise of unless I didnt heard of that. I'm new to ruby and rails also.
about the created_at, I'm using because is already created. and on this sentence that you gave me how I capture if its today? 
I think of using and argument

Comment: If you need to create one of these records per day, you need a `DATE` field that captures the day they're associated with. Then you can do `unless (user.banks.where(on_date: date))` to find one for a particular date, or `Date.today` for today.